# How add balance in mangopay wallet?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I have been working on mangopay PHP SDK. I have successfully created normal/legal users using same SDK.

But I am stuck in transfer API. I can not perform any transaction. I have already crated multiple users and corresponding wallet which I can see by [sandbox dashboard](http://dashboard.sandbox.mangopay.com/Users). But I cannot add balance in wallet for any user.

Can anyone please help me out and clear me for mangopay flow.

I also found one more [dashboard](https://panel.getmango.com/stores), But I don't know how it is related to my sandbox.

Each time I try to transfer money from one user to another user I always get error like : No sufficient balance in wallet. (Of course because I can not add amount for particular user)

Please help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful because "getmango.com" is nothing to do with "mangopay.com" to which your question actually refers

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the mangopay sample code, the functionality will be this. You have to MAKE SURE that the wallet ids are valid.

```
$mangoPayApi = new \MangoPay\MangoPayApi();
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientId = "mangopayuser";
$mangoPayApi->Config->ClientPassword = "mangopaypassword";
$mangoPayApi->Config->TemporaryFolder = "cache/dir/path";

$Transfer = new \MangoPay\Transfer();
$Transfer->AuthorId = $authorId;
$Transfer->DebitedFunds = new \MangoPay\Money();
$Transfer->DebitedFunds->Currency = "EUR";
$Transfer->DebitedFunds->Amount = 2500;
$Transfer->Fees = new \MangoPay\Money();
$Transfer->Fees->Currency = "EUR";
$Transfer->Fees->Amount = 500;

/**
* please make sure that $debitedWalletId and $creditedWalletId are valid wallet ids
**/
$Transfer->DebitedWalletID = $debitedWalletId;
$Transfer->CreditedWalletId = $creditedWalletId;

$result = $mangoPayApi->Transfers->Create($Transfer);
```

Comment: Hi, I am running into the same situation.and I have a question to address concerning this answer. **Is this still valid if the DebitedWalletID hav a balance of 0.00 EUR ?** because that is my worry the transaction is not going through.